# How to list docker images in Google container registry (GCR) through python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-registry

I'm trying to write a python script to auto-delete old prerelease docker images that are taking up space in Google container registry. I'm stuck in how can I authenticate google cloud in python script and list docker images in GCR.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Container Registry (GCR)](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry) implements (the de facto standard) [Docker Registry API HTTP V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api).

This means that you can use `docker`, `podman` and other tools that implement these APIs to interact with GCR and it means that you should use a 3rd-party client library (often provided by Docker) to implement interaction with a Docker Registry such as GCR.

Google (!) documents this on the page [Docker Registry API](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/docker-api)

There is no Google API to interact with GCR.

You can demonstrate this to yourself by running e.g. `gcloud container images list` with the `--log-http` flag to show that the underlying REST calls are of the form `http://gcr.io/v2/{repo}/tags/list`. This is documented on Docker's API page for [`GET tags`](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#get-tags).

I've not used this but Docker provides a [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and this **should** enable you to interact with any registry that implements the Docker Registry API HTTP V2 such as GCR.

You **must** authenticate to GCR using a suitable permitted Google identity. This is documented [Authenticating using the Docker Registry API](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/docker-api#auth)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Google Cloud Python clients` in your Python script.
Then use a service account and a download a Json key from the `GCP IAM page`.

You have to give the needed permissions to this service account in the IAM page.

Before to run the main of your `Python` script, you can do an authentication on GCP with in your bash terminal :

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=your_path/your_service_account.json
```

To list your `Docker` images, you can also use a `shell` script instead of a `Python` script. The following command list all the images of the current project from `GCR` :

```bash
gcloud container images list
```

As explain before, in order to use `gcloud` commands, you have to be authenticated with your service account or other identity.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list